# Tightly Attach Autocomplete dropdown with its text box- JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete

### Correct Image:

[image]

### Problematic image:

If i drag the Modal div on which autocomplete dropdown is visible, dropdown remain on its same place, I want it to move along with Modal Div.

[image]

### Autocomplete Css and text box:

```
.ui-autocomplete{
    z-index:1050;
    max-height:220px;
    overflow:auto;
}
<s:textfield id="id_txt_notification_send_recipient" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"  placeholder="" maxlength="200" disabled="true" />
```

How to achieve it?

### Edit:

```html
<div id="workItemCreateModal"  class="modal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <span class="required-astrcs"><s:text name='txt.global.required.astrcs' /></span>
    <h2 class="inner-heading">
     <s:text name="txt.wi.wicrthdr" />
    </h2>
   </div>

   <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="carrier-data">      
     <s:textfield id="id_txt_notification_send_recipient" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"  placeholder="" maxlength="200" />
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make a *container* set its `position: relative` put your  `textfield ` in it and set your `ui-autocomplete` `position: absolute` and use its `top` attribute accordingly.

Comment: a fiddle would be helpful here !